# Calling Rest Api from Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm having problems calling a rest api from a custom policy. I need the data sent into the rest api like the following

```
{
  "correlationId": "123456",
  "message": {
    "email": "test@somedomain.com"
  }
}
```

I have the following Claims Transformation

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateGetAadRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">

    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="message.emailAddress" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="correlationId" TransformationClaimType="correlationId" />
    </InputClaims>

    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="getAadRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
    </OutputClaims>

</ClaimsTransformation>
```

And I'm making the Rest Api call using the following Claims Provider

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Custom REST API</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="RestApiGetAad">
      <DisplayName>Call the Rest API</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{Settings:RestApiGetAadUrl}</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">getAadRequestBody</Item>
        <Item Key="ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens">true</Item>
        <Item Key="DebugMode">{Settings:RestDebugMode}</Item>
        <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Cannot process your request right now, please try again later.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="{Settings:RestApiUserName}" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="{Settings:RestApiPassword}" />
      </CryptographicKeys>

      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateGetAadRequestBody" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>

      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="getAadRequestBody" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="useAAD" PartnerClaimType="content.UseAad" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

It looks like the call is being made, however, there is nothing being sent in the body. Any idea what I'm  doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, this was issuing the wrong error code. Should have been [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK), as I did not have the claims that I was trying to use in the ClaimsTransformation. Think that posting here gave me a bit of [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and I walked the flow again spotting the issue