# Rest API call in custom policy in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am new and have tried to build custom policy for sign-in by invoking a REST API call to legacy.

The API expects below parameters as input:
client_id=fixed value, client_secret=fixed value, grant_type=fixed value, scope=fixed value, username=variable, password=variable

The above parameters are not for Azure valued but some fixed values that need to be sent in the request.

I have added few portions in the extensions custom policy but seems the request body is not forming correctly and I am getting the error The claims exchange User Migration Via Legacy  specified in step '1' returned HTTP error response with Code Bad Request and Reason 'Bad Request'.
What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Added my portion :

```
  <BuildingBlocks>
<ClaimsSchema>
  <ClaimType Id="RequestBody">
    <DisplayName>Request body</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>RequestBody</UserHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
<ClaimsTransformations>
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="username" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="password" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="client_id" DataType="string" Value="client" />
      <InputParameter Id="client_secret" DataType="string" Value="sec" />
      <InputParameter Id="grant_type" DataType="string" Value="grant" />
      <InputParameter Id="scope" DataType="string" Value="scope" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="RequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

```
<ClaimsProviders>
  <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST API to communicate with Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdp">
      <DisplayName>REST API call to communicate with Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">RequestBody</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateRequestBody" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="RequestBody" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tokenSuccess" DefaultValue="false" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="migrationRequired" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: I have referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991739/calling-rest-api-from-custom-policy to form the request body

Comment: Can you please add the REST API Technical Profile (with dummy values in the fixed value) which will help to provide you answer what is wrong in the profile.

Comment: I added my piece of code. Please check and let me know if I am sending the attributes in the correct format in the request body.

Comment: Are you calling the REST API in an OrchestrationStep, if yes try once by removing the password input and try or else you can call the REST API from the Validation technical profile of Self Asserted technical profile from where you are getting the email and password.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the actual JSON created by the claim transformation? Is it well formatted? You can make troubleshooting easy by displaying the output of  `<InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateRequestBody" />` before you actually use it as input claim inside the REST API technical profile. This will reveal what's going on with your JSON format.

To do that, first create a self asserted technical profile and add  `<InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateRequestBody" />` as an output claim transformation to it. Your output claim should be the claim which you will use later in next step in the journey.

In the user journey, add a step that calls the self asserted technical profile. Add next step with App Insights to write the output claim to App Insights( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights)

This will document claim value that REST API is receiving.

Comment: Can you provide an example with all of the XML? There are steps here that I don't know how to complete. Thanks!

Comment: How can I add an InputClaimsTransformation as an OutputClaimsTransformation? They seem incompatible.